# Like query for comma separated numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

I am trying to get data from a view which returns users name and tags (comma separated numbers). Now I want to get a user if it has a certain tag.

My view returns this:

```
 id |  name  |        tags        
----+--------+--------------------
  1 | Albert | 1,2,3,4
  2 | Isaac  | 11,22,33,40,50
  3 | Marie  | 44,110,220,330,500
  4 | Ray    | 111,222,333
```

I want to get a user which contains tag = 4. When I try to query using LIKE operation, it returns multiple users.

```sql
select * from users
  where tags LIKE '%4%';
```

Output:

```
 id |  name  |        tags        
----+--------+--------------------
  1 | Albert | 1,2,3,4
  2 | Isaac  | 11,22,33,40,50
  3 | Marie  | 44,110,220,330,500
```

**Desired Output:**

```
 id |  name  |        tags        
----+--------+--------------------
  1 | Albert | 1,2,3,4
```

How do I tackle this problem?

Online playground link: https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3zc7pfngm

Comment: use string_to_array and array operations.  (Or better yet, store your array as an array in the first place).  https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3zc7xyewc

Comment: Thanks, can you post this as an answer @jjanes

Comment: Please note that this is a sub-optimal data design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below query :-

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE ',' || tags || ',' LIKE '%,4,%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `LIKE` works in any database, but in PostgreSQL the [string_to_array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html) is your solution

```
select *
from users
where 4 = any(string_to_array(tags, ',')::int[]);
```

I assume that all your *tags* are integers. Adapt to `text` if not.